# Storing checkboxes state in current session/run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

My view including checkbox clickevent listener which should be fired every time a checkbox state had been changed:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

        <title>TestChckBox</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                $(document).on("click", "input.chks", function (e) {
                    var _this = $(this);
                    var isChecked = _this.is(':checked');
                    $.post("@Url.Action("UpdateInput","Search")?id=" + _this.attr("id") +
                                          "&newValue=" + isChecked, function (data) {
                                              // response stuff should be here
                                          });

        });
    });

</script>


    </head>
```

--

```
       @if (ViewBag.SliceList != null)
        {
            @*foreach(Pirsum.Models.HourSlice slice in this.Model) {*@

            foreach (var slice in ViewBag.SliceList) {
                <div  class="row">


          <input class="chks" type="checkbox" id="@HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("cb_slice." + @slice.SliceID)" />
                    <label for="@HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName("cb_slice." + @slice.SliceID)">@slice.SliceName</label>
                    <span class="info">@slice.StartTime - @slice.EndTime</span>

                </div>
            }
        }
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       }
            </body>
        </html>
```

The divs are populated correctly with several checkboxes and strings from an action that passes items in the viewbag to the view.

The problem is that the function above isn't working and the "UpdateInput" isn't fired in the search controller when checkboxes are getting clicked nor any click event on the client side.

What am I doing wrong? and how can I save the checkboxes state(checked and unchecked) properly in the session or in any other option I can temporary save the checked parameters set on the runtime?

Controller actions for reference, This one send data to body(related checkboxes and some other data for the matter)

```
public ActionResult TestChckbox()
{
    int iInstId = 1;

    Test.Models.DataLayer db = new Test.Models.DataLayer();
    Test.Models.TestDB.context = new Models.TestDB();

    IEnumerable<Test.Models.HourSlice> lst = db.GetSlices(context, iInstId).OrderBy(a => a.SliceID);
    ViewBag.SliceList = lst;
    return View(lst);
}
```

This action should be ran with checkboxes state when checking/unchecking the boxes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInput(int id, bool newValue)
{
    //do your saving here.
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your javascript debug console? Have you stepped through the javascript code to make sure it's working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery 1.4.4; `on` didn't exist yet in that version. You need to use `bind` or upgrade your version of jQuery.

Other than that, don't put scripts in the head of your HTML and if you do, definitely wrap them in `$(document).ready()`. Also, it's a hugely bad idea to attach a delegate to something as high-level as `document`. Every click, everywhere, will cause jQuery to query the DOM to see if it happened on an object with class `.chks`. You want to attach the delegate to the absolute closest parent you can get away with. Finally, based on your code you don't even *need* a delegate. Only use delegates when the something will be dynamically added to the DOM and still needs to trigger event handlers. IF the element is just there, from page load, then just attach the handler directly to the id or class.

Comment: It doesn't work with 1.8.3 neither, The event of on check won't be fired either way, not to mention passing it to the saving proccess.
Can you provide example on how to work it out?